# How to make login in AUTH (Laravel) with data coming from a third party API?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authentication

I'm developing a news app in laravel 5 for a client, but it already has a working system, and wants me to use the existing database for that system users can sign in to the news app. He developed an API JSON that returns me:

```
string(74) "{"Status":1,"Usuario":"John Doe Smith","Mensagem":"Login liberado!"}"
```

or if was an error

```
string(75) "{"Status":0,"Usuario":" John Doe Smith ","Mensagem":"Senha incorreta!"}"
```

How can I log in with AUTH from these two API responses?

Comment: Using **PHP -** **CURL** function you can call your third party API. Based on that API response, you can validate the login in custom middleware without using laravel Auth.

Answer (score 0):

**Create the user in the Laravel database**

Create a entry for each user in the Laravel database (use a database dump of the current database or a seeder etc). With this information available you can use the username to do a lookup for the user:

```
$user = User::where('username', '=', $username);

// Login with model
Auth::login($user, true);
// Or with ID
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, true);
```

This is just an example (and a fairly insecure one at that) but i would strongly recommend reading this part of the laravel documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

Answer (score 0):

To make it short :

```php
$response = json_decode($API);
if($response['Status']){
      $user = User::where('username',$response['Usuario']);
      Auth::login($user);
      // Do your things here
}
else{
      return response('Unauthorized',401);
}
```

**Note:** You should replace the `username` from the where closure to what your Usuario refers to in your database. i.e: *name*,*fullame*,*etc..*